# How to modify bootstrap 4.5 tooltip css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

With bootstrap  4.5.3 I make tooltip and I want to change default appearence.
With my styles defined :

```
.tooltip {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #ddff9d;
    color: #333333;
    width: 320px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px white;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1 !important;

    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #00acd6 !important;
    /*!important is not necessary if you place custom.css at the end of your css calls. For the purpose of this demo, it seems to be required in SO snippet*/
    color: #fff;
}

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: #00acd6;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
    border-right-color: #00acd6;
}

.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom-color: #00acd6;
}

.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
    border-left-color: #00acd6;
}
```

I have :
https://prnt.sc/wlwp1v

and I want how :

1. Change width of internal (blue) block to fill width+paddings
2. Set equal paddings of internal block with external
3. To align text inside of internal block to the left ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
That is actually fullcalendar 3.9 component and tooltip is rendered on fly with javascript code:

```
  eventRender: function (eventInfo, element, view) {
  let adHtml = '<b>' + eventInfo.title + "</b><br> " +
        '<u>{!! showAppIcon('expire_date') !!} Expired at : ' + eventInfo.start_formatted + '</u><br>'+
        '{!! showAppIcon('location') !!}&nbsp;' + eventInfo.adLocationsCount + '&nbsp;location(s)<br>' +
        '<small>Status : ' + eventInfo.status_label + "</small><br>" +
        '<small>' + eventInfo.description + "</small>"

    let tooltipOptions = {
        title: adHtml,
        html: true
    }

   element.tooltip(tooltipOptions)
```

I use this  bootstrhttps://bootswatch.com/solar as template...
I can not debug elements in browser's inspactor, as when mouse is hover tooltip is hidden...

Thanks!

Comment: Plz, include the respective HTML.

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: For which element is the tooltip. There is no html.

Comment: I modified : for any cell of day

Comment: This is the code so far you have provided: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJRBpxK

Comment: Please look at https://codepen.io/sergeynilov/pen/vYXVVBq. Originally I wanted to add width of tooltip popup, as it has a lot of content5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the width just use: `max-width: 400px;`. To left-align text just simply use `text-align: left;`

Replace your whole CSS with the given below:

```
.tooltip-inner {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYRXzro