# How to customize bs4dash tooltip in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, tooltip, bs4dash

I want to customize the tooltip in the following shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tooltip(
    actionButton("goButton", "Hier klicken!"),
    title = "This is a ridiculous blablabla example text
            even more bla bla bla",
    placement = "right"
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ideally the text is shown as flush left, the background color is another one and the tooltip-box is larger. Within the help of the bs4Dash package i found only the follwing link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ but i dont know where to place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) for different ways to modify css in your ShinyApp. This example makes inline css with many tooltip css specifications as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687115/how-to-modify-bootstrap-4-5-tooltip-css) on another question.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(HTML("
      .tooltip {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #ddff9d;
    color: #333333;
    width: 320px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px white;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1 !important;

    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #00acd6 !important;
    /*!important is not necessary if you place custom.css at the end of your css calls. For the purpose of this demo, it seems to be required in SO snippet*/
    color: #fff;
}

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: #00acd6;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
    border-right-color: #00acd6;
}

.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom-color: #00acd6;
}

.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
    border-left-color: #00acd6;
}")),
  
  tooltip(
    actionButton("goButton", "Hier klicken!"),
    title = "This is a ridiculous blablabla example text
            even more bla bla bla",
    placement = "right"
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```